# How to simulate an Oracle DB link in H2 database?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, h2

My problem is the following: I have to test an application which is written in Java Spring.
In real life the DB server will be an Oracle. There are some select where a DB link is used. 
(For example: select * from country@isem_db; )
In test environment we use H2 database which doesn't know this syntax.(@)
My question is : Is this somehow possible to make this Oracle syntax acceptable for H2 ? Is some workaround exists for it without modifying  the original source code?

Comment: It isn't possible without modifying queries in your application or sources of H2; H2 doesn't support this non-standard syntax. You can link tables from other databases in H2 too, but such linked tables use regular syntax with plain names.

Answer (score 2):

Your Oracle code should not contain embedded database links. Database link names may change across environments, which makes your code brittle. Or you may need to switch to using a local copy (or materialized view).

The correct approach is to use synonyms. In Oracle you would create a synonym for the remote table:

```
create synonym isem_country for country@isem_db;
```

Obviously you need to change your Oracle code to reference the synonym name instead of the remote table.

This gives you the solution for running in H2, providing you're using [a recent version which supports table synonyms](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/548). In H2 you would create a synonym with the same name but on the local table:

```
create synonym isem_country for country;
```